# Magento 2 GraphQL - Customer Token - Error

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, graphql

After enabling any recaptcha storefront, getting error of recaptcha.

**Error :**

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "ReCaptcha validation failed, please try again",
            "extensions": {
                "category": "graphql-input"
            },
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "generateCustomerToken"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "generateCustomerToken": null
    }
}
```

**GraphQL Query :**

```
mutation customerAccessTokenCreate {
  generateCustomerToken(
    email: "test@test.com",
    password: "Test@123"
  ) {
    token
  }
}
```

**Note :** After disabling captcha from admin (Admin Panel -> Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Security -> Google reCAPTCHA Storefront -> Storefront -> Enable for Customer Login -> *No*), It's working.

Comment: Hello @Vrajesh, are you passing the Authorisation: Bearer Your_Token in the header area? Also update the configuration using command 

bin/magento config:set oauth/consumer/enable_integration_as_bearer 1

Comment: In Customer Token also I need to pass ? @TarunBhalodia

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34731  refer this ticket, it is same as your problem

Comment: Thank you @TarunBhalodia. I have found the solution from above github post.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comment I have found the solutions from github (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34731)

So need to pass the Access Token created from Admin Panel.

Steps to create Admin Access Token : *Admin Panel -> System -> Extensions -> Integrations -> Add New Integration*.

Fill all the required details. (In API tab select Resources Access - Custom Or All) and Click on Save. Once saved need to Activate, so click on Activate Button.

Now Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Access Token, Access Token Secret are created.

Use Access Token.

Pass that Access Token In Headers : **Authorization :** *Bearer <access_token>*

**KEY :** *Authorization*
**VALUE :** *Bearer <access_token>*